# What is the shelf life of dried lotus seeds?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, seeds

Since the Mooncake festival is coming. I am thinking of making Mooncakes with some dried lotus seeds I bought a year ago. Could they still be safe to eat?

Comment: dried seeds should be *safe* to eat for quite a while, since bacteria and such can't really grow where there is no water. Whether they will be tasty or not depends on the quality of the seeds and how you stored them.

Comment: That's an answer @Esther

Answer (score 4):

Since bacteria and other pathogens can't really grow where there is no water, dried seeds and other dried items will remain *safe* to eat for quite a while. However, how *tasty* they will be depends on the quality of the seeds and how they were stored. Seeds can go stale and lose flavor over time, or the fats in them can become rancid. You can try tasting one to be sure you'd still want to eat them before making a larger recipe.

Comment: What is the taste of a good lotus seed?

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 whatever you would expect it to taste like when new? It would also likely taste distinctly *bad* if it had gone rancid or stale.

Comment: So I just soak it in water then put it in my mouth?

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 I guess so, you don't need to swallow it, just see if it tastes bad (probably fine but you never know)

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 the rancid fats will usually develop a plastic-like smell usually noticeable before tasting, and a waxy/stickier texture. If you can already smell it, they're definitely rancid.

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 Go to a Chinese (or generic Asian) supermarket, buy some Mooncakes and find out :-)